# For programming, is "add" translated using "agregar" or "añadir"?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico, informática

Is *agregar* or *añadir* (or something else) more correct when describing computer programming actions, for example when adding a string to an array?

```
arr.append("hola")
```

Is that:

> Agregar la cadena a la matriz

or:

> Añadir la cadena a la matriz

What about when describing adding a new function to a class?

> Agregue la nueva función a la clase Foo

Final situation: "`self` must be added as the first parameter"

> `self` debe añadirse como el primer parámetro

Comment: [Opiniones sobre uso de Ñ en nombre de variables en C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/22393/2027)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a developer myself, I tend to use `añadir` more frequently than `agregar`, mostly because the latter is related to "aggregation" which is also a programming concept and in some contexts might need some disambiguation; although both are generally valid.

If you want to be more specific, you can use `concatenar` instead when talking about appending to a string.

The only exception would be when talking about arithmetic addition, where one should almost always use `sumar`.

Comment: Good answer. // I like *concatenar* because it has only one meaning.  But I don't know what people say in practice, since I did not learn to program until after leaving Latin America.